# Should a text object start with 9 users?

Tags: text-object

I am using the 2.77rc2.
I just added a new text mesh and the font option each have 9 users.

[image: Font Users]

Is this normal, or should this be reported as a bug?

It seems weird because adding any other object, the object starts with only one user. (itself)

Comment: I get 5.  My guess is the  UI uses Bfont, which is why it is disabled and also can't be removed.  Any other loaded  font and it works as expected.

Comment: Upvoted for the absurdity. :-)